# timezone incorrect in odoo log file

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In my country timezone is GMT+5.30,so I changed the timezone accordingly in preferences menu but in odoo log file the timezone is still GMT.How to change this?

Config file,

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_user = openpg
db_password = openpgpwd
addons_path = C:\Users\odooGit\addons
pg_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150922\PostgreSQL\bin
xmlrpc = True
xmlrpc_port = 8069
xmlrpcs = True
xmlrpcs_port = 8071
syslog  = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature isn't available in Odoo at the moment even if you set timezone to something like `Africa/Lagos` Odoo will use `UTC` time for the logs, if you're on Linux a workaround to start the odoo server with `--syslog`, which would uses the machine's timezone just like it does for other system logs.

so start your Odoo server like this

`./odoo.py --syslog`

or you can just set it in the config file with

`syslog = True`

Note that specifying `--syslog` will redirect the logs to the redirect the logs to the system log files (usually `var/log/syslog`), if you want a separate file, you'll have to do some extra work yourself.

if you're on Ubuntu checkout `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` (rsyslogd)

if you're on CentOS which uses syslogd checkout `/etc/syslog.conf`

Comment: Your answer is working in linux but on windows its not working

Comment: yeah it's a Linux specific answer, though there are syslog alternatives for windows e.g http://syslog-win32.sourceforge.net/ and some articles i found http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2012/configuring-syslog-agent-windows-server-2012.html and http://www.howtogeek.com/107069/how-to-remotely-collect-server-events-using-syslog/. i don't know exactly how they work but i believe you should be able to reproduce these steps with them. if you do don't hesitate to post an answer

Comment: IMHO i don't really see why you should run odoo on windows, there are many downsides...you can't have multiple workers, there is no `fork` on windows so you might have problems spawning new processes from odoo, and also Linux > Windows :)

Comment: Thanks for the response