# How to change odoo server timezone?

Tags: python, postgresql, timezone, odoo-8

I want to change odoo server timezone which is used to store values in database. Default it uses UTC. I want it to use  system timezone. I have tried it by changing in config file by mentioning timezon="Asia/Kolkata" and also by giving it it parameter list by mentioning --timezon="Asia/Kolkata" but its of no use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801527/timezone-incorrect-in-odoo-log-file

Comment: But it changes only log time. It does not change the time of database. If I am saving a form with datetime field, On UI it shows user timezone but in database it uses UTC timezone. I want to change that timezone to custome timezone